# How to 301 redirect URL with PHP parameters to root DIR in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have searched how to redirect url with parameters to root dir but I can't get it to work :(

This is what the .htaccess code looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^phpnuke/modules\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

I have url such as "http://www.domain.com/phpnuke/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=60" and I want to redirect it to "http://www.diagonally.org/"

Comment: There is no `id=1` in your URL, so how could this be redirected?

Comment: Thanks man. I now got it. I need to replace the "id=1" with my php variables such as "name=News&file=article&sid=60"

Comment: Ok, now it shows it works correctly with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but it still doesn't work with my site on the real server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep redirect rule before default WP rewrite rule and match correct query string:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=News&file=article&sid=60
RewriteRule ^phpnuke/modules\.php$ /? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try some thing like this

```
# For sites running on a port other than 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: What would this do? Do I need to add this to already existing code?

Comment: Thanks for these links. It shows that the "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1" condition was not met.